# How can I recover from a failed hibernation wake up

Tags: recovery-mode

I am trying to login after a failed a hibernation (my computer just hangs there)
Now I can not get into the system. When I try to login, it tells me I am in emergecy mode, and I need to login as root. After I do that, I don't know what to do next.
[image: login]

When I try recovery mode, I get this. I can not interact with the TUI (it also asks me to login as root, and after I do it, I can't do anything)
[image: recovery mode]

This is what I see in

```
$ journal -xb
```

[image: journal]

So what are my options here? I do have a live CD, can I use that to help me recover the system?

Comment: Have you tried a fsck from the Live DVD? In terminal run `sudo fsck /dev/sdxy` where sdxy is your root drive and partition.

Comment: Hi @C.S.Cameron, yes, and it says it's clean

Answer (score 2):

It turns out another partition is also broken.
I run `fsck` on that partition as well, and it is working now.

Comment: Thank you for letting us know what worked for you.